# How to check all the web-element in the list are displayed

Tags: list, selenium, for-loop, xpath, header

[image: Footer with textlinks]

I want to verify 'About Us', 'Contact Us' and 'FAQ' text links under 'More Information' footer section are displayed or not

How I can check it? Do I have to get xpath of each list web-element and then check whether its displayed on the web page? or lists of all web-elements at once,and then trace through for loop?

And also help me in writing xpath for 'About Us' element

Comment: Which language binding are you using?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify all at once or you can verify individually also, try the below code which will fetch all the options, verifies whether those are present or not and checks they are displayed or not:

```
// Get all the options using the below line
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer-section']//a"));

// Check they are present or not?
if(elements.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("=> The Options are present...");
} else {
    System.out.println("=> The Options are nor present...");
}

// Check they are displayed or not?
for(WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText()+" is displayed? "+element.isDisplayed());
}
```

If you want to verify individually then you need to do like below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer-section']//a[text()='About Us']")).isDisplayed();
```

Comment: Please take some time to indent your code properly. Badly indented code blocks are prone to _downvotes_

Comment: @DebanjanB, Thank you, I will format it properly from now onwards

Comment: @ DebanjanB : Thank  you so much. It helped me!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify that each element is present or not then yes you need to check separately for every element. Though you can make one generic method to check its present or not using assert.
For example:

```
public void checkElementPresent(String elementText){
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()="+elementText+"]")).size()>0);
}
```

Or if you dont want to use assert then you can use if else condition as well, like:

```
public void checkElementPresent(String elementText){
 if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()="+elementText+"]")).size()>0){
        System.out.println("Element is present");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Element is not present");
    }
}
```

And you can just call the method by sending the text of the link you want to verify if its present or not:

```
checkElementPresent("About Us"); or
checkElementPresent("Contact Us");
```

Comment: Above answer helped me. Thanks!

Comment: @Avinmita please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you :)